# AWK file reformatting

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

I'm struggling to reformat a comma separated file using awk.  The file contains minute data for a day for multiple servers and for multiple metrics
e.g 2 records, per minute, per server for 24hrs

Example input file:

```
server01,00:01:00,AckDelayAverage,9999  
server01,00:01:00,AckDelayMax,8888  
server01,00:02:00,AckDelayAverage,666  
server01,00:02:00,AckDelayMax,5555  
.....  
server01,23:58:00,AckDelayAverage,4545  
server01,23:58:00,AckDelayMax,8777  
server01,23:59:00,AckDelayAverage,4686  
server01,23:59:00,AckDelayMax,7820  
server02,00:01:00,AckDelayAverage,1231  
server02,00:01:00,AckDelayMax,4185  
server02,00:02:00,AckDelayAverage,1843  
server02,00:02:00,AckDelayMax,9982  
.....  
server02,23:58:00,AckDelayAverage,1022  
server02,23:58:00,AckDelayMax,1772  
server02,23:59:00,AckDelayAverage,1813  
server02,23:59:00,AckDelayMax,9891
```

I'm trying to re-format the file to have a single row for each minute with a unique concatenation of fields 1 & 3 as the column headers

e.g the expected output file would look like:

```
Minute, server01-AckDelayAverage,server01-AckDelayMax, server02-AckDelayAverage,server02-AckDelayMax  

00:01:00,9999,8888,1231,4185  
00:02:00,666,5555,1843,8892  
...  
...  
23:58:00,4545,8777,1022,1772  
23:59:00,4686,7820,1813,9891
```

Comment: You could try the `join` command for data grouping. Otherwise, associative arrays in `awk` with the timestamp string as a key.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using GNU `awk`. Call this as `awk -F, -f script input_file`:

```
/Average/ { average[$2, $1] = $4; }
/Max/ { maximum[$2, $1] = $4; }
{
    if (!($2 in minutes)) {
        minutes[$2] = 1;
    }
    if (!($1 in servers)) {
        servers[$1] = 1;
    }
}
END {
    mcount = asorti(minutes, smin);
    scount = asorti(servers, sserv);
    printf "minutes";
    for (col = 1; col <= scount; col++) {
        printf "," sserv[col] "-average," sserv[col] "-maximum";
    }
    print "";
    for (row = 1; row <= mcount; row++) {
        key = smin[row];
        printf key;
        for (col = 1; col <= scount; col++) {
            printf "," average[key, sserv[col]] "," maximum[key, sserv[col]];
        }
        print "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{
    a[$2]=(a[$2]?a[$2]","$4:$4)
}
END{
    for ( i in a ) print i,a[i]
}' File | sort
```

If `$4` has `0` values:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '!a[$2]{a[$2]=$2} {a[$2]=a[$2]","$4} END{for ( i in a ) print a[i]}' | sort
```

`!a[$2]{a[$2]=$2}`: If array with `a` with Index `$2` ( the time in Minute) doesn't exit, array `a` with index as `$2`( the time in Minute) with value as `$2` is created. True when Minute entry first time occurs in line.

{a[$2]=a[$2]","$4}: Concatenate value `$4` to this array

`END`: Print all values of in array `a`

Finally pipe this awk result to sort.

Comment: many thanks , this work perfectly in most circumstances.One observation I've seen is if the first metrics of a minutes value is 0, the data is not transposed properly. e,g server01,00:01:00,AckDelayAverage,0
server01,00:01:00,AckDelayMax,0
server01,00:02:00,AckDelayAverage,666
server01,00:02:00,AckDelayMax,5555

Comment: cat test |  awk -F, -v OFS=, '{a[$2]=(a[$2]?a[$2]","$4:$4)}END{for ( i in a ) print i,a[i]}'   00:01:00,0  
00:02:00,666,5555

Comment: That is not because of minute values but because '$4' is `0` . I have edited the answer with solution to overcome this.

Comment: thank-you.    For my understanding could you explain how the first part is working ? (  !a[$2]{a[$2]=$2} {a[$2]=a[$2]","$4 )

Comment: Updated the answer. If not clear you can read how [awk array](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_12.html) works.

Answer (score 0):

run awk command : **./script.awk  file**

```
#! /bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    FS=",";
    OFS=","
}
$1 ~ /server01/ && $3 ~ /Average/{
    a[$2]["Avg01"] = $4; 
}
$1 ~ /server01/ && $3 ~ /Max/{
    a[$2]["Max01"] = $4; 
}
$1 ~ /server02/ && $3 ~ /Average/{
    a[$2]["Avg02"] = $4; 
}
$1 ~ /server02/ && $3 ~ /Max/{
    a[$2]["Max02"] = $4; 
}
END{
    print "Minute","server01-AckDelayAverage","server01-AckDelayMax","server02-AckDelayAverage","server02-AckDelayMax"
    for(i in a){
        print i,a[i]["Avg01"],a[i]["Max01"],a[i]["Avg02"],a[i]["Max02"] | "sort"
    }
}
```